# UNION a subquery with sparql

Tags: subquery, union, sparql

I am looking for an easy way to get the relations from all relations of a concept. For example:
You search for a concept with the name "Abc". It has some relation to other objects, such as "D", "Ef", "Ghi". The result looks like:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| concept | relation      | value   |
=====================================
| uri:Abc | skos:narrower | uri:D   |
| uri:Abc | skos:narrower | uri:Ef  |
| uri:Abc | skos:broader  | uri:Ghi |
-------------------------------------
```

So now you know the relations of "Abc". If you want to know the relations from the relations of "Abc" you can use a subselect. Such as the query below. But what I want is both of the results. I will know the relations of "Abc", but also from "D", "Ef", "Ghi".

```
SELECT (?v1 as ?concept) ?relation ?value WHERE
{
    ?v1 ?relation ?value .
    {
        SELECT ?c1 ?r1 ?v1 WHERE 
        {
            ?c1 rdf:label "Abc" .
            ?c1 ?r1 ?v1 .
        }
    }
}
```

This is my current query. In production I'm use a filter in it, but for this example it is not necessary.

Comment: how many columns do you want in this?  you want the "second-level" relation as an additional column right?

Comment: I want 3 columns. Because I want to use a depth. It should be possible to get the relations of the relations of the relations.. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for a subquery here, and my initial attempt was much more complicated than what you actually needed.  If you want all the subject, predicate, object triples where subject is either the thing with label "Abc" or something that it's connected to, you can use this query:

```
select ?s ?p ?o {
  ?c rdfs:label "Abc" .
  ?c (<>|!<>)? ?s .
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
```

**?c rdfs:label "Abc"** binds **?c** to the Abc object, as in your query.  Then **?c (<>|!<>)? ?s** makes **?s** be either **?c** or something one relation away from it.  This works because **<>|!<>** is a wildcard (since every property is either **<>** or it isn't, and **?** says zero or one occurrences).

For instance, with this data and query, you get the following results:

```
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.
@prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>.
@prefix : <urn:ex:>.

:Abc rdfs:label "Abc" ;
     skos:narrower :D, :Ef ;
     skos:broader :Ghi .

:D skos:narrower :Da, :De, :Do .

:Ghi skos:narrower :Ginormous, :General .
```

```sql
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?s ?p ?o {
  ?c rdfs:label "Abc" .
  ?c (<>|!<>)? ?s .
  ?s ?p ?o
}
```

```
-------------------------------------
| s    | p             | o          |
=====================================
| :Ghi | skos:narrower | :General   |
| :Ghi | skos:narrower | :Ginormous |
| :D   | skos:narrower | :Do        |
| :D   | skos:narrower | :De        |
| :D   | skos:narrower | :Da        |
| :Abc | skos:broader  | :Ghi       |
| :Abc | skos:narrower | :Ef        |
| :Abc | skos:narrower | :D         |
| :Abc | rdfs:label    | "Abc"      |
-------------------------------------
```

The construct version of this (since you're essentially getting triples back) would be:

```sql
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix : <urn:ex:>

construct { ?s ?p ?o }
where {
  ?c rdfs:label "Abc" .
  ?c (<>|!<>)? ?s .
  ?s ?p ?o
}
```

Comment: And if you don't want 6 columns but just 3, with the subject, predicate, and object, then you should use a CONSTRUCT query instead of a SELECT. That way, you get back RDF triples - far easier.

Comment: I want 3 columns to show. Column 1 is the concept, 2 the sort of relation, 3 the related concept. Do you have an example with `CONSTRUCT`?

Comment: @JonasB I realized that my original answer was overly complicated.  I've updated with a simpler query that will have the three columns you want.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor This is much better. Now I get all the information I want. Can I make this query transitive? So I can get the data from all relation as far as possible or with a given maximum?

Comment: That wasn't part of your original question, but it's easy enough to do. Just change that? Operator into an asterisk

Comment: You're right. This solved my whole problem! Many thanks!

Comment: @JonasB [Property paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) are a very powerful addition to SPARQL 1.1.  It may be helpful to skim over that section of the standard to familiarize yourself with what's possible.  An early draft of the standard actually included an `{m,n}` notation for lengths of paths.  It didn't make it into the standard, but Virtuoso supports it (and maybe other endpoints, too). If you wanted an upper bound on the path length, it'd be worth a shot.

Comment: Thats true. I'm using Fuseki as endpoint server and it supports the property path also. I'm currently using your query with `{,m}` and it works fine!